# how do we know that the writing file is done

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsfilemanager, nsdocument

I am downloading image from server and saving that locall
`[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`
but how does I know when the writing is over to update the UI. I have searched for a call back but I am not able to find any thing.

how do we know when the writing file is done?

Answer (score 5):

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;
```

Returns you the bool.

If you have doubt like if above method returns write initiation success, Use following method to write a file where you have errorPtr as Out param. 
If paramOut is nil you have written file successfully.

```
 - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)writeOptionsMask error:(NSError **)errorPtr;
```

Comment: I am using this one only. but the problem is it will return if it successfully start writing the file. I don't think it will return after writing is done.

Comment: @Mohan modified Answer

Comment: still same problem. I think it is async call.

Comment: When do some file read or write operation. It is safe to do it in main thread.

Comment: if I have huge file then writing file in main therad will make bad user experience.

Answer (score 2):

> - (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)aURL atomically:(BOOL)atomically

Return Value
YES if the operation succeeds, otherwise NO.